# Не доступен метод PUT

Tags: php, apache, slim

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой, что у меня не доступен метод PUT. Я пишу некоторый Api на PHP Slim.

Сервер:

Apache 2.4 x64

PHP 5.6.31

При попытке отправить put запрос на какой-то адрес, я получаю следующий ответ: `{"message":"Method not allowed. Must be one of: GET, POST"}`.

Запрос я пытался отправлять как через Ajax, так и через Postman. Ответ один и тот же.

Я не понимаю, куда копать нужно, чтобы разрешить метод PUT. Кстати, с методом DELETE всё работает нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, я ошибся в ссылке запроса... Забавно, я отправлял запрос на /users, а надо было на /users/{id}. Вопрос можно считать закрытым.